# Wordpress Hide Widget If $_Session Is Active?

Tags: widgets

I was wondering if there is an easy solution to add some php "if" code when my website tries to show the widgets and if it has $_SESSION I set on homepage (based on the source of which they came) not to show one of them?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is via `dynamic_sidebar()`

```
<?php
if ($a == $b)  // Your $_SESSION stuff
  dynamic_sidebar( 'Right Sidebar' );
?>
```

Any widgets contained in the "Right Sidebar" will now be loaded based on your condition. You should use this with `register_sidebar()`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar